# DNS registro.br direcionar para Azure Web App

Tags: microsoft-azure, dns

Tenho um web service e um site hospedados em uma máquina virtual Azure acessada por um link do tipo `meunome.cloudapp.net`. Tenho também o registro `www.meunome.com.br` no `registro.br`. Quero direcionar meu registro para minha máquina virtual no Azure.

Ao tentar direcionar, o `registro.br` pede um URL para Servidor Master e outro para Servidor Slave 1. Como direcionar para minha única máquina virtual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Servidor Master` e o `Servidor Slave 1` são para quando você ira usar outro servidor de DNS.

Se você desejar usar o servidor de DNS do `registro.br` você deverá selecionar `utilizar os servidores DNS disponibilizados gratuitamente pelo Registro.br` ou `Editar Zona` caso já tenho feito esta escolha.

Você [deve](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/):

1. Logar no [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), selecione seu serviço de cloud, selecione **Dashboard**, e encontrar a seção de **quick glance**.
2. Criar uma entrada `CNAME` de `www` para seu `Site URL` (`meunome.cloudapp.net`)

[image: Obter Site URL]

3. Criar uma entrada `A` de `@` para seu VIP (IP Virtual Público)

[image: Obter VIP]

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar. Não tenho um Website no Azure, só o Cloudapp. O site roda sobre um Tomcat na máquina virtual. Ainda assim, é possível seguir estes mesmos passos?

Comment: Atualizei para Azure Cloud Services, veja se você consegue agora

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação. Problema era com o registro.br. Não estávamos conseguindo criar um registro CNAME ou A de forma simples, ele sempre exigia que colocássemos um Master e um Slave. Bastou escolher a opção de "utilizar os servidores DNS disponibilizados gratuitamente pelo Registro.br".

Comment: Ok, vou incluir essa informação na resposta para que ela sirva de referência para outras pessoas no futuro